# Android Fingerprint only allows 5 attempts at a period of time

Tags: android, encryption, fingerprint, android-security, android-fingerprint-api

I am developing an Android App that requires fingerprint to open an Activity. I just noticed when I unlock my phone using my fingerprint, the number of attempts to scan a fingerprint in my app only becomes 4.

For example:

- Phone is locked
- Unlock phone using fingerprint
- Open my fingerprint app
- Cannot attempt to scan a fingerprint more than 4 times

Another scenario:

- Fingerprint app is open
- Only 5 attempts will be accepted, app will no longer attempt to scan a fingerprint
- Wait for a period of time, again, only 5 attempts within a duration will be accepted

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research and found the [Android 6.0 Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/6.0/android-6.0-cdd#7_3_10_fingeprint).

This was stated under the Fingerprint Sensor section:

> Device implementations with a secure lock screen SHOULD include a fingerprint sensor. If a device
>   implementation includes a fingerprint sensor and has a corresponding API for third-party developers,
>   it:
>
> MUST rate limit attempts for at least 30 seconds after 5 false trials for fingerprint
>   verification.

So.. I guess there's no workaround for this at the moment.

Comment: Corrent document link is here -> https://source.android.com/compatibility/6.0/android-6.0-cdd#7_3_10_fingeprint

Comment: shortly: maximum = 5 false trials
Thanks

Comment: > [C-1-5] MUST rate limit attempts for at least 30 seconds after five false trials for fingerprint verification. 
https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#7_3_10_1_fingerprint_sensors

Answer (score 3):

Came across this stackoverflow when searching for the same issue I was having.

Anyways, with the latest API [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#display-login-prompt), we can now customize the behavior by overriding the AuthenticationCallback

```
BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
    override fun onAuthenticationError(
        errorCode: Int,
        errString: CharSequence
    ) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult
    ) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
    }

    // called when an attempt to authenticate with biometrics fails
    // i.e. invalid fingerprint
    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed()
        // keep track of a counter here and decide when to dismiss the dialog
        biometricPrompt?.cancelAuthentication()
    }
}
```